# Join two tables brings mismatch values MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with >4million records i need to make a select query with where two columns match bring both tables value on this match and then i will insert that into a 3rth table:

This is table A: (bitfinex)

[image]

This is table B: (Kraken)

[image]

I need to do a  SELECT where timestamp and exchange_pair matches, as you can see in this image from table B the same timestamp can have multiple exchange_pair, what i need to do is match those with the other table columns and bring both table content

[image]

this was the query i used at once but when analyzing the results i had some mismatch values on the joins ( i did not found the relation, it was not either timestamp or the exchange pair) i wonder if my query syntax is right for the result im looking for.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO spreads(timestamp,exchange_pair,platform_a,platform_b,a_bid_price,b_bid_price, high_value,spread_percentage,spread)
SELECT B.timestamp, B.exchange_pair,'bitfinex' as platform_a,'kraken' as platform_b,
 B.bid,
 K.bid_price,
 (SELECT IF (B.bid>K.bid_price,B.bid,K.bid_price)),
 (SELECT (((ABS(K.bid_price - B.bid))*100)/(SELECT IF (B.bid>K.bid_price,B.bid,K.bid_price)))),
  ABS(K.bid_price - B.bid)  AS spread
FROM bitfinex AS B
JOIN kraken AS K
 ON B.timestamp = K.timestamp
JOIN kraken AS K2
 ON B.exchange_pair = K2.exchange_pair
WHERE K.exchange_pair = B.exchange_pair AND B.timestamp = K.timestamp ;
```

im still confused if using inner join or just join, also i added the "Where" clause to make sure exchange pair and timestamp matches.

Comment: There is likely no need to join table K twice. Remove the K2 join completely.

Comment: Also `INNER JOIN` = `JOIN`, they mean the same thing. It's just two different ways (one's a shorthand notation) to say the same thing.

Comment: Please [do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) use images for DDL/DML code here - use a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1 :** `INNER JOIN` & `JOIN`  both are same thing.

**Point 2 :** No need to do an extra join on `K2`

You can use this :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO spreads(timestamp,exchange_pair,platform_a,platform_b,a_bid_price,b_bid_price, high_value,spread_percentage,spread)
SELECT B.timestamp, B.exchange_pair,'bitfinex' as platform_a,'kraken' as platform_b,
 B.bid,
 K.bid_price,
 (SELECT IF (B.bid>K.bid_price,B.bid,K.bid_price)),
 (SELECT (((ABS(K.bid_price - B.bid))*100)/(SELECT IF (B.bid>K.bid_price,B.bid,K.bid_price)))),
  ABS(K.bid_price - B.bid)  AS spread
FROM bitfinex AS B
JOIN kraken AS K
 ON B.timestamp = K.timestamp
and 
 K.exchange_pair = B.exchange_pair  ;
```